# Using Shiny to Create a Scatterplot with dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am creating an interactive application using Shiny. I want to use the inputs in ui.R to filter a data set so that it will change the xyplot for the inputs that filter the data set. Here is my code.

ui.R is:

```
library(shiny) # load the shiny package
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(h4('What makes a batter swing?', align = "center")),
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("PlateCount", label = "What is the count?",
            choices = c("0-0" = '0-0', "0-1" = '0-1', "0-2" = '0-2', "0-3"='0-3'),
            selected = '0-0'),
sliderInput("endspeed", "What is the Maximum end speed of the pitch?", min=38, max=95, value=50),
radioButtons("relief", label = "Relief Pitchers?",
             choices = c("Relief", "Non-Relief",
                         "All Pitchers"), selected = "All Pitchers")
),
mainPanel(
plotOutput("plot")
)
)
)
```

I am trying to get the plot to display with ggvis or xyplot in mosaic, but I get error messages with both.

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(ggvis) # Load shiny package
Pitchers$count= as.character(Pitchers$count)
Pitchers$Swing <- as.character(Pitchers$Swing)
#here is trying mosaic
shinyServer(function(input, output){
plotData <- reactive({ 
df <- Pitchers %>%
  filter(count==input$PlateCount)
})
output$plot <- renderPlot(xyplot(y~x, group=Swing, pch='.', data=df, auto.key=TRUE))
})

#here is trying ggvis
shinyServer(function(input, output){
plotData <- reactive({ 
df <- Pitchers %>%
  filter(count==input$PlateCount)
  })
 output$plot <- renderUI(Pitchers %>%
                          ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>%
                          layer_points())
})
```

With the mosaic option, the error message pops up reading "invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'".
With the ggvis option, the plot shows up in the plots window of RStudio, but in the application, I am getting the error message:
Error: argument is of length zero

To clarify I am not trying to create the two plots at the same time, they are just the different ways I am trying to make the plot. I comment one out when I run the app.

Comment: `output$plot <- renderPlot(xyplot(y~x, group=Swing, pch='.', data=df, auto.key=TRUE))` , did you mean to write `data=plotData()` instead of `data=df`?

Comment: Maybe you need `filter_(~count==input$PlateCount)` in the ggvis version?

Comment: The first comment fixed the xyplot command, but the ggvis version does not show up in the application, it only shows up in the plot panel of RStudio.

Comment: @Megan, can you provide a reproducible dataset or indicate where you found it if public?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say for certain without a reproducible dataset (I will update accordingly if provided) but you need to update your both your ui.R and server.R for `ggvis` plots.  First, you want to use `bind_shiny` for the `ggvis` object.  Second, your ui.R you should replace `plotOutput` with `ggvisOutput`.  The following assumes you have variables `x` and `y` within `Pitchers`.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  plotData <- reactive({ 
    df <- Pitchers %>%
      filter_(count==input$PlateCount)
  })

  plotData %>%
    ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    bind_shiny("plot")
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h4('What makes a batter swing?', align = "center")),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("PlateCount", label = "What is the count?",
                choices = c("0-0" = '0-0', "0-1" = '0-1', "0-2" = '0-2', "0-3"='0-3'),
                selected = '0-0'),
    sliderInput("endspeed", "What is the Maximum end speed of the pitch?", min=38, max=95, value=50),
    radioButtons("relief", label = "Relief Pitchers?",
                 choices = c("Relief", "Non-Relief",
                             "All Pitchers"), selected = "All Pitchers")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plot")
  )
)
)
```